# Leaflet convert meters to pixels

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am creating an app using leaflet

I have the leaflet map up and running and have a Geoserver service that return points that are shown on the map.

I have one additional field that is distance between my Points on the Map and it is in meters ?

My question is how could I convert it to pixels? Is there any Leaflet function or anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function with the [L.GeometryUtil](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#destination) library.

[L.GeometryUtil CDN](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/leaflet-geometryutil)

```
function disToPixeldistance(distance){
  var l2 = L.GeometryUtil.destination(map.getCenter(),90,distance);
  var p1 = map.latLngToContainerPoint(map.getCenter())
  var p2 = map.latLngToContainerPoint(l2)
  return p1.distanceTo(p2)
}
```

But think of that the pixel distance is changing every time you zoom

Comment: Thank you so much for answering :) and is there any way I can handle when zoom is changing ?

Comment: Listen on the `zoomend` event:  `map.on('zoomend',function recalcDistance(){ //... your code with the disToPixeldistance() call })`. If it works, pls accept the answer

Comment: Will check it out tomorow, accepted thank you for answering